# PHP create multiple arrays for each of the value passed in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Check out my code snippet below.

```
    $data = [];

        foreach($dates as $date)
        {
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $this->days; $x++)
            {
                $data[] = clone $date;

                $date = $date->subDays('1');
            }
        }
```

`$dates` is an array consisting of an x amount of carbon instances. For each of the dates, I want to create a new set of dates, using the above code snippet.

`$this->days` can be any number. If it's set to 1, I will create one addtional date as opposed to the one I already have. Example:

I have two dates:

```
2016-01-10 // 10th of january 2016
2016-05-15 // 15th of may 2016
```

Using the above code snippet, I will create an additional `$date` for each of my `$dates` in my array, by subtracting one day from it and adding it to the array. So afterwards, I will have an array consisting of four dates:

```
$data = ['2016-01-10', '2016-01-09', '2016-05-15', '2016-05-14']; // Example array, not the actual output
```

It works as expected. But what I want, is for each of the dates, to be put in a new object, or array, instead of having them all in one single array. So for the `january` dates in my example, I want an array, or object, and also for the `may` dates.

Any ideas of how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to create the sub-arrays:

```
$data = [];

foreach($dates as $date)
{
    $partition = []; // create new sub-array
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $this->days; $x++)
    {
        $partition[] = clone $date; // add to it

        $date = $date->subDays('1');
    }
    $data[] = $partition; // now add to main array
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks a lot! I should have known this btw, since it's obvious.. But it's always good to learn :)